# `nawk` "doesn't work" with `make`? Why?

Tags: bash, colors, awk, make

I have the following alias:

```
alias mca_color='nawk '"'"'BEGIN { arr["Creating shared object"] = "1;31";} \
{ l = $0; for (pattern in arr) \
{ gsub(".*" pattern ".*", "\033[" arr[pattern] "m&\033[0m", l); } print l; }'"'"
```

I use similar aliases for coloring other outputs (using more patterns, but this is just for example).

So, this alias works, if I use it like:

```
$ echo "-ne Creating shared object test.so ..." | mca_color
```

the `echo` is printed in red. **BUT**, when I try:

```
$ make | mca_color
```

and even

```
$ make 2>&1 | mca_color
```

the result is **not** colored (and yes, `make` does "print" the same text at the end if its execution).

Any ideas?

---

I thought there could be something with child processes or something, but obviously the pipe works - tried it with `grep`, tried to redirect the output into a file, everything works.

Even this doesn't work (the text is printed, but not colored):

```
$ make 2>&1 | grep 'a' | mca_color
```

Comment: Have you compared the two outputs at byte level?

Comment: All your suggested versions work for me, that is the text is printed in red.

Comment: @MarcusRickert - At byte level - no, how can I do this? And even the `make` works? Interesting, I have no idea why it doesn't work here.....

Comment: By _byte level_ I mean that you try to look at the contents in _hex mode_. Some editors support this. This way you can find unvisible characters that might corrupt the pattern search. As a first test you can also compare the file lengths of the files that you pipe the output into and see if there is any difference in length.

Comment: @MarcusRickert - I figured it out. You can see my answer. Stupid situation..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out, almost accidentally.

It appeared, that there was another `alias make='colormake'` and `colormake` is a script, containing:

```
/usr/bin/make "$@" 2>&1 | /usr/share/colormake/colormake.pl/usr/bin/make "$@" 2>&1 | /usr/share/colormake/colormake.pl
```

which explains a lot. Removing the `alias` for `colormake` fixed the "issue".

Comment: No idea why `colormake` didn't produce any colors, but I don't really care.